# Which is better: "Plug-in" or "plugin"?

Tags: word-choice, hyphenation

What is the correct word, *plugin* or *plug-in*?  Does it depend on the context?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As others have mentioned, most dictionaries (including the OED) list plug-in as appropriate. I'd seriously shy away from calling *plugin* incorrect—I mean, just look how many hits you can get with [Firefox and plugin](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=firefox+plugins). In my experience, especially with computer programs and on the Internet, *plugin* is much more common than *plug-in*. Taking a descriptivist standpoint, I'd put my weight behind *plugin*.

Comment: Yes. I think it's a common phenomenon that hyphens eventually get dropped when a word becomes more commonplace. Compare with *electronic mail* -> *e-mail* -> *email* (nowadays perfectly acceptable form).

Answer (score 9):

**The correct word is plug-in.**

Every dictionary I can find plus wikipedia all state the word being "plug-in" while a few do mention they are sometimes called "plugins", that just seems to be in incorrect usage.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plug-in

I would post more links but my rep will not allow me.

And if you also want to know the act of plugging something in it would be "I am going to plug in the lamp."

Comment: The verb is _to plug in_, similarly to _to log in_. The noun derived from _to log in_ is _login_; that is why I was wondering if it was _plugin_. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: It should be said, though, that **online** is now accepted, while in the olden days it was insisted by the prescriptivists that it should be **on-line.**

Comment: Dictionaries run behind common usage

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically *plug-in* is the correct one, but practically both are widely used. (Mozilla, for example, calls them *plugins*.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could it be that _plugins_ is used for the plural, and _plug-in_ for the singular?

Comment: Nah, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure "plugin" is the wave of the future (like "email"). I'm a tech writer and I'm trying to decide which spelling to use in documentation. My copy of the "Microsoft Manual of Style" has "plug-in" with a hyphen but it's a bit out of date (10 years old, to be precise). I'll probably go with "plugin" since that's the way our developers spell it.